# List cards with icon in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to make a list of cards that has an image as a background and at the bottom 3 icons with their respective text.
The first image is what this piece of code does, the second would be the optimal result, but I don't know how to do it.

[image]

[image]

```
 Expanded(
                    child: GridView.count(
                        crossAxisCount: 1,
                        children: <Widget> [
                          Card(
                            semanticContainer: true,
                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc> (context).add(NavigationEvents.SystemsPageClickedEvents);
                              },
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget> [
                                  Image.asset('assets/images/test.png'),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          ),
                          Card(
                            semanticContainer: true,
                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc> (context).add(NavigationEvents.SystemsPageClickedEvents);
                              },
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget> [
                                  Image.asset('assets/images/test.png'),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          ),
                          
                        ]
                    ),
                  ),
```

If I use this code I get an error: **Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.** *Usually, this means that the Placed widget has the wrong RenderObjectWidget ancestor. Typically, placed widgets are placed directly within Stack widgets.
The Offensive Positioned is currently placed inside a ConstrainedBox widget.*
The final result is about what I want because as you can see it creates too much space between one card and another. The problem is the **Container** but i don't know how to have the same result without using **height: 180,**. How can I solve both problems?

[image]

```
Expanded(
                child: GridView.count(
                    crossAxisCount: 1,
                    children: <Widget> [
                      Stack(
                          children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 180,
                            child: Positioned.fill(
                               child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc> (context).add(NavigationEvents.SystemsPageClickedEvents);
                                  },
                                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/test.png', fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                                ),
                            ),
                          ),
                            Positioned(
                              bottom: 140,
                              left: 0,
                              right: 0,
                              child: Container(
                                height: 60,
                                color: Colors.green,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      const Icon(Icons.house),
                                      const Icon(Icons.house),
                                      const Icon(Icons.house),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),



                    ]
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: For this layout, you can use Stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem.

```
Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 170),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                       // BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc> (context).add(NavigationEvents.HomePageClickedEvents);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                        height: 180,
                        child: Card(
                          color: blue,
                          semanticContainer: true,
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/test.png', fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                          //shadowColor: Colors.white,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          elevation: 0,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )])))),
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey there instead of Card you can wrap it with a Stack.

```
Card(
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc> (context).add(NavigationEvents.SystemsPageClickedEvents);
            },
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/test.png',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Container(
            height: 60,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  const Icon(Icons.house),
                  const Icon(Icons.house),
                  const Icon(Icons.house),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Stack()` widget and to position child widget to bottom use `Positioned()` widget inside.

A basic structure is given here.

```
Stack(
      children: [
        // Image ( any image widget can be used. network, asset ect)
        Image.network(url),
        // Icons
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.black54,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                // Icon One
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home), onPressed: () => {}),
                // Icon Two
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home), onPressed: () => {}),
                // Icon Three
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home), onPressed: () => {}),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
```